# d3js wrong or no text in x-axis

Tags: d3.js

My data is like this:
[{"month":1,"year":2013,"sumValue":60599.0,"countRecords":2976,"date":"2013-01-01T00:00:00"},{"month":2,"year":2013,"sumValue":52922.0,"countRecords":2688,"date":"2013-02-01T00:00:00"},{"month":3,"year":2013,"sumValue":62585.0,"countRecords":3072,"date":"2013-03-01T00:00:00"}]

Code Snippets

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width + margin.left + margin.right]);
var x_extent = d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.month });
x.domain(x_extent);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
svgGroup.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")") .call(xAxis);
```

I have no chance to get the values 1 to 12 in the x-axis (the next step should be to display the name of the month - but how can I do this, if I even don't get the values)
What will be displayed is something (stupid) like this:
0.0 0.1 0.2.....

If I try this (mentioned in another post):

```
d3.svg.axis().scale(x).ticks(d3.time.months, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b"));
```

nothing is shown.

I think I'm missing some basic understandig. Can somebody help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance

©a-x-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use time scales (which is what your second code snippet suggests), you will have to instantiate the scale thusly:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width + margin.left + margin.right]);
var x_extent = d3.extent(data, function (d) { return new Date(d.date); });
x.domain(x_extent);
```

Note that in this case you will have to convert your `.date` strings to `Date`s (as shown in `d3.extent`) before passing them to the scale.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it didn't help me. 
Now only a "01 AM" is shown in the left corner. Nothing else. 
I'm really a bit confused....

Comment: Did you add the line with `.ticks(..).tickFormat(..)` that you mention in your post?

Comment: Can you post your complete code please, preferably in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Your solution was fine. Now it works.
My data (above mentioned was only a part of it) was corrupt.